# What is the generic alternative of Array?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, generics

In C# some collections such as `ArrayList` and `HashTable` have generic alternatives which are `List<T>` and `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`.

**Does Array also have a generic alternative?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking for the generic collection type that most closely resembles an array, then you probably want a `List<T>`.  But it's not really the same thing.

To expand on what others have said:  the point of having generic types is so that a programmer can then use *type-specific* instances of those generic types, based on the needs of the current program.  Arrays are *already* type-specific.  You can always just take a `T[]`.

For example, look at this simple function definition:

```
void SomeFunction(int[] x)
```

You could also think of it like this:

```
void SomeFunction<T>(T[] x)
```

where the programmer just chose to call it with an `int` for the type parameter:

```
SomeFunction<int>(myIntArray)
```

Comment: Can you have a two or more dimensional List<T> like you can have in Array?

Comment: You can have List<List<T>>, but like I said before: it's not really the same thing.  And if you're using 2-D arrays that often you're probably doing something else wrong.

Comment: See this (written by one of the C# language designers): http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/22/arrays-considered-somewhat-harmful.aspx

Answer (score 6):

No - just use a strongly typed array, e.g. `int[]`. It's relatively rare to use a "weakly typed" `Array` in the first place - in fact, I don't believe you can really create one. Every `Array` is really a strongly-typed one, even if you don't refer to it that way.

Comment: I'd say T[] is the generic alternative of Array, except it existed before generics.

Comment: how about arrays with reference type elements? you could have an object array or animal array..

Comment: That's just string[] or Animal[]. I only picked int[] as a random example - there's nothing important about the int part really.

Answer (score 4):

Array has always been, with special compiler support, somewhat generic.

E.g. System.Array allows objects in, but an int[] does not.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Jon's answer

Arrays have no generic alternative because it's perfectly fine to have a generic array.

```
public static T[] CreateArray<T>(T item1, T item2) {
   T[] array = new T[2];
   array[0] = item1;
   array[1] = item2;
   return array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for a generic alternative as when you define an array you state the type of the array. All the classes you mentioned are simple collection classes. An aray is a totally different data structure.

Comment: Can you please explain the difference?